# How to compile Alamofire with Swift 2.3 on Xcode8 for iOS10

Tags: mongodb, cocoapods, alamofire, xcode8, swifty-json

Receiving the following error when importing Alamofire: 'Module compiled with Swift 3.0 cannot be imported with Swift 2.3'

```
import Alamofire
```

I am reproducing code that was originally written with:

- Xcode7
- iOS 9
- Alamofire 3.4
- Swift 2.3

Reproducing it with:

- Xcode8
- iOS 10
- Alamofire 3.4 or 3.5
- Swift 2.3 (Swift Compiler: Use Legacy Swift Language Version = 'Yes')

Podfile Contents:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'TodoList' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
```

Is there a way to import a version of Alamofire that was compiled with Swift 2.3?

I have also tried to get code to work using Swift 3.0 (Swift Compiler: Use Legacy Swift Language Version = 'No'). When I use Swift 3.0, there is no error importing Alamofire, however I receive a different error when making my Alamofire request, "extra argument 'method' in call". Please see the below Alamofire request:

```
Alamofire.request( APIEndpoints.newTodoURL(userId), method: .post, parameters: parameters ,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
```

I am okay with using either Swift 2.3 or Swift 3.0, so long as I can perform the above Alamofire request.